# What are the differences and relationships between online plant taxonomy databases (POWO, WFO, WCSP, WCVP), and is one considered the most reliable?

Tags: botany, taxonomy

Each of these databases has their own summary of their aims and process - but they rarely seem to mention each other in comparison. It's hard to figure out what differences or relationships exist between them. It seems like some of them use data from others, but not exclusively.

Should one of these be considered the primary or central source for botanical taxonomy? Are each of these databases reinventing the wheel independently, or are they just presenting the same data with different interfaces? Is any of them considered the most reliable or complete?

- [World Checklist for Selected Plant Families (WCSP)](https://wcsp.science.kew.org/)
- [World Checklist for Vascular Plants (WCVP)](https://wcvp.science.kew.org/)
- [Plants of the World Online (POWO)](https://powo.science.kew.org/)
- [World Flora Online (WFO)](https://wfoplantlist.org/plant-list)

Comment: Please check this open access article : https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/nph.18961# It proposes a comparison of WFO, WCSP, LCVP and WorldPlants and explain why and how they differ. WCVP, POWO and WCSP are the same basically.